# how to get values from dict in template with for loop?

Tags: ansible

I have two dict file like

teams.yml

```
{
  "teams": [{"gid": 10125,"location": ["hq"],"name": "aa","users": ["chenhu","chouf"]},
            {"gid": 10126,"location": ["hq"],"name": "ac","users": ["guoj","yangc"]} ]

}
```

users.yml

```
{
    "users": [{"name": "changc","uid": 20000},
                    {"name": "changb","uid": 20001} ]
}
```

I want to generate a file using template , so I start with two seperate for loop for test

test.j2

```
{% for i in users %}
{{ i.uid }} {{ i.name }}
{% endfor %}

{% for j in teams %}
{{ j.users }} {{ j.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

and ansible run with errors

```
AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'users'
```

but teams dictonary did have users attr , why ansible can not get the value ??

so if I want to create a for loop in jinja2 template the condition is
when user's name show in teams then write down user's name and teams name
how do I do it ?

```
{% for i in users %}
 {for j in teams %}
  {if i.name in j.users %}
{{ i.name }}_{{ j.name }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

that's my first thought , but I have no idea how to do now ..
any suggestions ??

Comment: For people reproducing this - can you tell us more about the environment you have?
Ansible version? Which folder structure you use/playbook/role/inventory to pass those values teams/users into the template?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - teams.yml
    - users.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for i in users %}
          {{ i.uid }} {{ i.name }}
          {% endfor %}

          {% for j in teams %}
          {{ j.users }} {{ j.name }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    20000 changc
    20001 changb
  
    ['chenhu', 'chouf'] aa
    ['guoj', 'yangc'] ac
```

---

Q: *"**When the user's name shows in teams, write down the user's name and team name.**"*

A: Use *json_query* and put the data into a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        users_teams: "{{ users_teams|d({})|
                         combine({item: {'teams': my_teams}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_users|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
      vars:
        my_users:
          - {name: changc, uid: 20000}
          - {name: changb, uid: 20001}
          - {name: chenhu, uid: 20002}
        my_query: "[?users.contains(@, '{{ item }}')].name"
        my_teams: "{{ teams|json_query(my_query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  users_teams:
    changb:
      teams: []
    changc:
      teams: []
    chenhu:
      teams:
      - aa
```

Comment: >>Your code works fine,

No , it did not work. ansible just throw out the error message like usual 
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'users'"

and I really like the final result in your reply , that's what I want, but I have no idea how to do , I will try to undestand those filters you used. thanks !

Comment: [edit] your question and add [mre] details.